# In typescript can a property decorator infer an optional type?

Tags: typescript

In typescript, can a property decorator infer an optional type?

I.e. If you have the following:

```
@Column()
ua?: string
```

Could @Column() recognise that ua is an optional type?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question! The only two properties I know if that can be optional are types in object literals and types in interfaces, and both cannot be decorated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. Right now the only data you can read from the decorator is the type of the property, name of the property, and class where this property is (even this is achieved throw the `reflect-metadata`).